# Pluralize certain methods

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am working with the new Yii2 Advanced template, is there a way to pluralize certain calls to the restful API?

For example i want to have the generic GET request for all items for the controller 'countries'
BUT then if im doing a POST/Patch request for 1 record i want the controller to be 'country'

Comment: actually jpa does something like this with table names, if I remember correctly, (or was it cakePHP?) From there you could at least steal the name pluralization for english names.

Comment: I'm not infront if it right now but yii allows for this. You might want to check the basic yii rest example as they use pluralizing. It should at least point you to the right direction in the API

Comment: I can get the pluralize to work but its an all or nothing setting. ALL controllers will be set based on that setting.

So for example:
I would like to be able to do a GET as /countries
I would like to do a PUT as /country/1